# Разделить получаемые даные на день сегодняшней даты

Tags: excel, vba

Есть макрос, работает как ВПР. Ищет данные из основного файла в файле доноре, затем в доноре копирует соответствующие данные из заданного столбца и вставляет в заданный столбец основного файла. Нужно при выгрузке в основной файл к полученным данным добавить /DAY(TODAY()-1), чтобы вставлялось значение взятое из донора деленное на сегодняшнюю дату -1.

```
Sub updateV()
Dim aData(), aShop(), aRes()
Dim sPath As String, dDate As Date, bFlag As Boolean
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Const sFolder As String = "C:\Manager\..."
Const lRwStart As Long = 12 ' начало диапазона'
    With ActiveSheet
        i = 114 ' завершение диапазона'
        If i < 5 Then Exit Sub
        aShop = .Cells(lRwStart, 1).Resize(i - lRwStart + 1, 1).Value
    End With

    ReDim aRes(1 To UBound(aShop), 1 To 1)
    dDate = Date

    Do
        sPath = sFolder & "Экономический отчет (" & Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ").xls"
        If Dir(sPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then bFlag = True: Exit Do  ' файл найден'
        dDate = dDate - 1 ' если не найден, уменьшаем дату для следующего имени файла'
    Loop Until dDate = Date - 5 ' просматриваем максимум 5 файлов (5 дат)'

    If bFlag = False Then MsgBox "Нет файла-донора", 64, "ОШИБКА": GoTo err_

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath) ' открыть книгу'
        With Worksheets("по филиалам") ' если есть сомнения в наличии листа, нужна доп. проверка'
            i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
            aData = .Range("A1:G" & i).Value
        End With

        .Close
    End With

    For k = 1 To UBound(aShop)
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 7) ' записываем найденное'
        Next i
    Next k

    With ActiveSheet
        lClmn = Application.Match("среднее", Range("A11:ZZ11"), 0)
        .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
        .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист'
    End With
err_:
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В цикле есть строка с комметарием "*записываем найденное*". Дополнить ее (по вопосу непонятно, нужно делить на день или на дату - выбрать нужный варант):

```
If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 7) / Day(Date - 1)

If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 7) / (Date - 1)
```